# PHP $_GET hide url

Tags: php

I am writing PHP code for my hosting web page.
I create a search domain filled on page with $_GET to check if domain was available. I need to protect my $GET function in code.

The $GET code to process searching of a domain:

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
$domena = ($_GET['search']);
}
```

HTML CODE
I have a submit button with FORM POST ACTION and I get the URL:

`www.domain.com/index.php?search=domain.com`

I need know if I can hide the URL `search=domain.com`

Note - I don't want to use AJAX or other language, just PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide search parameter, then send it by POST method and accept it by $_POST instead of $_GET.

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $domena = ($_POST['search']);
}
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding picky, using POST instead doesn't "hide" the search parameter, it's either not there as using POST now, or If they still use a link somewhere that sets the param then it will show in the URL ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using the $_POST method? The data sent from the user will be in the HTTP request and not in the url. The $_GET method would be posted in the url.

Mozilla does a good job explaining [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).

Make sure to specify method $_POST in your form. For example:

```
<form action="http://foo.com" method="post">
  <input name="say" value="Hi">
  <input name="to" value="Mom">
  <button>Send my greetings</button>
</form>
```

Then to retrieve your data, use the same code you posted in your question but change $_GET to $_POST